# CakePHP date 5 days from now using CakeTime

Tags: cakephp

I need to create a date to be stored in `mysql`. The date is 5 days from now. I thought maybe `CakeTime::dayAsSql('+5 days')` but I'm missing a parameter which the documentation doesn't describes and also I dont really know if this will give me what I need. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read the documentation at all? I'm asking because `CakeTime::dayAsSql()` is clearly not what you want:

> Returns a partial SQL string to search for all records between two
>   times occurring on the same day.

Use `CakeTime::format()`:

```
echo CakeTime::format('+5 days', '%B %e, %Y %H:%M %p');
```

Comment: yeah, I just noticed "The Book" is not cakephp's documentation; I have been reading that the whole time. I'll just read the javadocs from now on <.<